# Why doesn't Google Maps API show maps in Israel?

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I wish to use Google Maps API in my website to embed a map of Israel with details of roads and streets.  However, when I use it, I cannot see any road details, even that such information is available on [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com).

Any idea why that is?  Can it be resolved?

Comment: You don't get any details? I can see road names for most (but not all) of the roads in Israel.

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.
Can see roads and cities all around but not at Israel

Answer (score 2):

According to a Google employee in this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-data-api/browse_thread/thread/6a2a8fac9735280e?pli=1), Google Maps is "not contractually allowed to expose the high quality Israel data in the API at this time." I am assuming this is for security reasons.

You can keep track of their Map coverage [here](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html).

Comment: it is a licensing issue